# Using Visual Studio 2022 Image Library after downloading

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have downloaded the provided zip file from Microsoft and seen that it has very small icons any advice on how I can install and use them in visual studio 2022 pro

I would like to be able to insert images dynamically into my vb.net project as follows

```
      Me.tsExit.Image = CType(resources.GetObject("tsExit.Image"), System.Drawing.Image)
```

Doing this currently results in no image being shown. Trying to use the asset import and choosing the image I need from the ones downloaded StatusErrorOutline.png results in a very blurry image meaning that it is not the right way of using the downloaded images.

Comment: That library is very old and has not been maintained in a very long time.  Almost all images were created in an era when 800x600 monitors were still common.  Increasing their size for modern monitors inevitably turns them blurry.  Google "freeware images" to get ahead, don't bother with that library.

Comment: The PNG images in all those libraries are samples / preview rendering, with base size (IIRC, 16x16) of the actual image. You're supposed to use the XAML / SVG in WPF or the SVG version (which needs to be rendered to the desired size before use) in WinForms -- Also note that the 2022 and 2019 libraries are a subset of the *big guy*, the Visual Studio 2015 Image Library, which also contains the `.AI` version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure to understand your problem. assuming tsExit is a pictureBox, you can use imageList component to store images like this :

```
 Dim ImageList1 As New ImageList
        ImageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("d:\\img\myFace.png"))
        ImageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("d:\\img\bottle.png"))
        ImageList1.Images.Add(Image.FromFile("d:\\img\dog.png"))


        PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(0) 'show myface.png
        PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images(1) 'show bottle.png
        'etc....
```